# Segmentation fault while executing c program

Tags: c

I am getting segmentation fault error in the following program
The code i have written is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/l2cap.h>
#include "devicescan.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include<time.h>
void send_message_function(char*);
typedef struct node NODE;
static int pckt = 0;

NODE *first=0, *temp = 0;

int c = 0;
int main()

{

int i = 0, iret1, count = 0;
while (1) {
    first = (NODE *) malloc(sizeof(NODE));

    pckt = pckt + 1;
    if (c == 0 || c == 4) {
        sleep(2);
        printf("device scanning\n");
        first = deviceDiscovery();
        printf("here");
        c = 0;
        temp = first;
    }

    while (first != 0) {
        char *dest=malloc(21);
        sleep(2);
        sprintf(dest, first->val);
        printf("device::%s\n", dest);
        //send_message_function(dest);
        first = first -> ptr;
        bzero(dest, 18);

    }
    free(first);
    first = temp;
    c = c + 1;
   }
 }
 void send_message_function(char *dest)

 {
 printf("in fun");
 struct sockaddr_l2 addr = { 0 };
 int s, stat, status;
 char buf[17] = { 0 };
 char data[20];
 int bytes_read;
 printf("in fun");
  s = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_SEQPACKET, BTPROTO_L2CAP);
  printf("in fun");
// set the connection parameters (who to connect to)
 addr.l2_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
 addr.l2_psm = htobs(0x1001);
 //addr.l2_psm = htobs(channel);
 str2ba(dest, &addr.l2_bdaddr);
 status = connect(s, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr));
if (status == 0) {

    printf("Sending message");
    sprintf(data, "%d : message from master", pckt);
    stat = write(s, data, sizeof(data));
    bytes_read = read(s, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if (bytes_read > 0) {
        printf("received %s:%d", buf, pckt);

    }

    bzero(data, 20);
    printf("\n");
  }

  if (status < 0) {

    perror("uh oh");
  }
  sleep(1);

  close(s);

 }
```

devicesacn.h file is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci_lib.h>
//  Pre processor  Directive  for  Memory  Leakage
struct node {
 char val[18];
 struct node *ptr;
  };
 typedef struct node *SNODE;

SNODE deviceDiscovery() {

 typedef struct node NODE;

 int count = 0;
 NODE *head, *first, *temp;

//head = (NODE *) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
inquiry_info *ii = NULL;
first = 0;
int max_rsp, num_rsp;
int dev_id, sock, len, flags;
int i;
printf(" DEVICE SCANNING....\n");
char addr[19] = { 0 };
char name[248] = { 0 };
dev_id = hci_get_route(NULL);
sock = hci_open_dev(dev_id);
if (dev_id < 0 || sock < 0) {
    perror("opening socket");
    exit(1);
}

len = 8;
max_rsp = 255;
flags = IREQ_CACHE_FLUSH;
ii = (inquiry_info*) malloc(max_rsp * sizeof(inquiry_info));
num_rsp = hci_inquiry(dev_id, len, max_rsp, NULL, &ii, flags);
if (num_rsp < 0)
    perror("hci_inquiry");
//head = (NODE *) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
for (i = 0; i < num_rsp; i++) {
    ba2str(&(ii + i)->bdaddr, addr);
    memset(name, 0, sizeof(name));
    if (hci_read_remote_name(sock, &(ii + i)->bdaddr, sizeof(name), name, 0)
            < 0)
        strcpy(name, "[unknown]");
    head = (NODE *) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    //first = (NODE *) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    temp = (NODE *) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    strcpy(head->val, addr);
    if (first != 0) {
        temp->ptr = head;
        temp = head;
    } else {
        first = temp = head;
    }
    fflush(stdin);

}

free(ii);

close(sock);
printf("returning value");
return first;
}
```

while debugging this program iam getting a segmentation fault at sprintf(dest,first->val) stement in the main function inside while.
I think i have allocated memory for variables,then why i am getting this error?  can anyone please help me.

Comment: If by debugging you mean using a debugger, why don't you peek into`first` and `first->val` before the call to `sprintf`? If you don't mean using a debugger, why aren't you?

Comment: When debugging, are you using GDB. If so, then when is the segfault happening in the while loop (first iteration?). I think what is happening is that it gets to the last node and when it goes to the next node, that node wasn't properly set up at NULL or 0 and defaulted to garbage data. As such, it passed the while conditional but the garbage data pointed to an illegal memory access resulting in the segfault. It's really hard to tell on my end without stepping through the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not allocating the memory to the `ptr` in structure.

```
first = first -> ptr; // In this if the ptr is null then you are accessing the next iteration first->val you are getting the segmentation fault.
```

After that while using the `sprintf`  you have to use conventional string.

```
sprintf(dest,"%s",first->val);
```

You can check that before accessing the first->val  may like

```
if ( first != NULL )
```

Comment: ,now the program execute without segmentation fault.but there are memory leaks in the devicediscovery() function.how can I solve that too, sorry for again asking.thanks in advance.

Comment: In that function I think you are not freeing the temp and head variable. In a else condition, `first=temp=head`. In this You can free the temp that is storing the head pointer.